# Why is my Ajax not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to use the Marvel API to do a school project so I've made a function to make a request to the Marvel server but I only receive the following back.

[image: object]

What is the problem?

```js
function GetComic() {
  var publicKey = 'e99561b7db2b414b085c39de1c7ed4ab';
  var privateKey = 'dc00398114b3a9a4fbd20d8a318d54530c11659f';
  var timestamp = Date.now();;
  $.ajax({
      url: 'https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        apikey: publicKey,
        hash: md5(timestamp + privateKey + publicKey),
        ts: timestamp
      }
    })
    .done(function(d) {
      console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function(r) {
      console.log(r);
    })
    .always(function() {
      console.log("complete");
    });

}

$('#btSearch').click(function() {
  GetComic();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/placemarker/jQuery-MD5/master/jquery.md5.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="inputSearch">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btSearch">Search</button>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: better remove all key just put `somekey` there.

Comment: does https://gateway.marvel.com allow CORS request?

Comment: thanks for giving us your public and private key for this API...maybe better to edit the example :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax function seem to correct but I did't see where you define the response for it so try this. Then we'll see what you get.

```
.done(function(response) {
    console.log("success",response);
})
```

> Update

You said that your ajax not work when you add button. It's because when you use the button it's will submit your form then the page is reload. So to make it's not submit the form. You can just easy edit your click event like this.

```
$('#btSearch').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //add this line to prevent form to submit
    GetComic();
});
```

Comment: I already figured out what the problem is!
The button that fires the function is inside a <form> if I take the form works if I put it crashes.
But why?

Comment: Can you provide me the form ?

Comment: <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="inputSearch">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btSearch">Search</button>
          </form>

Answer (score 0):

It seems your publicKey/privateKey doesn't have access.
Try this.

```js
function GetComic() {
 var publicKey = 'e45e89f50a97cd63e9d439ec81d9f903';
 var privateKey = 'c814304d6e7b47cf0271ea4dad732022f2bef7f1';
 var timestamp = Date.now();;
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {apikey: publicKey, hash:md5(timestamp+privateKey+publicKey),ts: timestamp}
 })
 .done(function() {
  console.log("success");
 })
 .fail(function(r) {
  console.log(r);
 })
 .always(function() {
  console.log("complete");
 });

}


//---------------------------------BTN CLICK -------


$('#btSearch').click(function(){
 GetComic();
});


// --------------------------------MD5 FUNC -------
var md5 = function (string) {

   function RotateLeft(lValue, iShiftBits) {
           return (lValue<<iShiftBits) | (lValue>>>(32-iShiftBits));
   }

   function AddUnsigned(lX,lY) {
           var lX4,lY4,lX8,lY8,lResult;
           lX8 = (lX & 0x80000000);
           lY8 = (lY & 0x80000000);
           lX4 = (lX & 0x40000000);
           lY4 = (lY & 0x40000000);
           lResult = (lX & 0x3FFFFFFF)+(lY & 0x3FFFFFFF);
           if (lX4 & lY4) {
                   return (lResult ^ 0x80000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
           }
           if (lX4 | lY4) {
                   if (lResult & 0x40000000) {
                           return (lResult ^ 0xC0000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
                   } else {
                           return (lResult ^ 0x40000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
                   }
           } else {
                   return (lResult ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
           }
   }

   function F(x,y,z) { return (x & y) | ((~x) & z); }
   function G(x,y,z) { return (x & z) | (y & (~z)); }
   function H(x,y,z) { return (x ^ y ^ z); }
   function I(x,y,z) { return (y ^ (x | (~z))); }

   function FF(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
           a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(F(b, c, d), x), ac));
           return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
   };

   function GG(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
           a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(G(b, c, d), x), ac));
           return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
   };

   function HH(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
           a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(H(b, c, d), x), ac));
           return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
   };

   function II(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
           a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(I(b, c, d), x), ac));
           return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
   };

   function ConvertToWordArray(string) {
           var lWordCount;
           var lMessageLength = string.length;
           var lNumberOfWords_temp1=lMessageLength + 8;
           var lNumberOfWords_temp2=(lNumberOfWords_temp1-(lNumberOfWords_temp1 % 64))/64;
           var lNumberOfWords = (lNumberOfWords_temp2+1)*16;
           var lWordArray=Array(lNumberOfWords-1);
           var lBytePosition = 0;
           var lByteCount = 0;
           while ( lByteCount < lMessageLength ) {
                   lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
                   lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
                   lWordArray[lWordCount] = (lWordArray[lWordCount] | (string.charCodeAt(lByteCount)<<lBytePosition));
                   lByteCount++;
           }
           lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
           lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
           lWordArray[lWordCount] = lWordArray[lWordCount] | (0x80<<lBytePosition);
           lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-2] = lMessageLength<<3;
           lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-1] = lMessageLength>>>29;
           return lWordArray;
   };

   function WordToHex(lValue) {
           var WordToHexValue="",WordToHexValue_temp="",lByte,lCount;
           for (lCount = 0;lCount<=3;lCount++) {
                   lByte = (lValue>>>(lCount*8)) & 255;
                   WordToHexValue_temp = "0" + lByte.toString(16);
                   WordToHexValue = WordToHexValue + WordToHexValue_temp.substr(WordToHexValue_temp.length-2,2);
           }
           return WordToHexValue;
   };

   function Utf8Encode(string) {
           string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
           var utftext = "";

           for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

                   var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

                   if (c < 128) {
                           utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
                   }
                   else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                           utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                           utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
                   }
                   else {
                           utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                           utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                           utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
                   }

           }

           return utftext;
   };

   var x=Array();
   var k,AA,BB,CC,DD,a,b,c,d;
   var S11=7, S12=12, S13=17, S14=22;
   var S21=5, S22=9 , S23=14, S24=20;
   var S31=4, S32=11, S33=16, S34=23;
   var S41=6, S42=10, S43=15, S44=21;

   string = Utf8Encode(string);

   x = ConvertToWordArray(string);

   a = 0x67452301; b = 0xEFCDAB89; c = 0x98BADCFE; d = 0x10325476;

   for (k=0;k<x.length;k+=16) {
           AA=a; BB=b; CC=c; DD=d;
           a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S11,0xD76AA478);
           d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+1], S12,0xE8C7B756);
           c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S13,0x242070DB);
           b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+3], S14,0xC1BDCEEE);
           a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S11,0xF57C0FAF);
           d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+5], S12,0x4787C62A);
           c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S13,0xA8304613);
           b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+7], S14,0xFD469501);
           a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S11,0x698098D8);
           d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+9], S12,0x8B44F7AF);
           c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S13,0xFFFF5BB1);
           b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+11],S14,0x895CD7BE);
           a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S11,0x6B901122);
           d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+13],S12,0xFD987193);
           c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S13,0xA679438E);
           b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+15],S14,0x49B40821);
           a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S21,0xF61E2562);
           d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+6], S22,0xC040B340);
           c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S23,0x265E5A51);
           b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+0], S24,0xE9B6C7AA);
           a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S21,0xD62F105D);
           d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+10],S22,0x2441453);
           c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S23,0xD8A1E681);
           b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+4], S24,0xE7D3FBC8);
           a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S21,0x21E1CDE6);
           d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+14],S22,0xC33707D6);
           c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S23,0xF4D50D87);
           b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+8], S24,0x455A14ED);
           a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S21,0xA9E3E905);
           d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+2], S22,0xFCEFA3F8);
           c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S23,0x676F02D9);
           b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+12],S24,0x8D2A4C8A);
           a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S31,0xFFFA3942);
           d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+8], S32,0x8771F681);
           c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S33,0x6D9D6122);
           b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+14],S34,0xFDE5380C);
           a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S31,0xA4BEEA44);
           d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+4], S32,0x4BDECFA9);
           c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S33,0xF6BB4B60);
           b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+10],S34,0xBEBFBC70);
           a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S31,0x289B7EC6);
           d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+0], S32,0xEAA127FA);
           c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S33,0xD4EF3085);
           b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+6], S34,0x4881D05);
           a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S31,0xD9D4D039);
           d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+12],S32,0xE6DB99E5);
           c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S33,0x1FA27CF8);
           b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+2], S34,0xC4AC5665);
           a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S41,0xF4292244);
           d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+7], S42,0x432AFF97);
           c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S43,0xAB9423A7);
           b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+5], S44,0xFC93A039);
           a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S41,0x655B59C3);
           d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+3], S42,0x8F0CCC92);
           c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S43,0xFFEFF47D);
           b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+1], S44,0x85845DD1);
           a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S41,0x6FA87E4F);
           d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+15],S42,0xFE2CE6E0);
           c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S43,0xA3014314);
           b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+13],S44,0x4E0811A1);
           a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S41,0xF7537E82);
           d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+11],S42,0xBD3AF235);
           c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S43,0x2AD7D2BB);
           b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+9], S44,0xEB86D391);
           a=AddUnsigned(a,AA);
           b=AddUnsigned(b,BB);
           c=AddUnsigned(c,CC);
           d=AddUnsigned(d,DD);
     }

    var temp = WordToHex(a)+WordToHex(b)+WordToHex(c)+WordToHex(d);

    return temp.toLowerCase();
}
```

```html
<button id="btSearch">Search</button>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```